# How do I change windows skin in api

Tags: api, skinning

I really wonder how winamp did it. I tried to change a drawing code to draw on title bar at ncpaint. it was run well but it was complex and it didn't draw,choosing another window.
I searched some source code or article but they used other ways... how do I do it?...

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Well, Winamp just creates a borderless, decorationless window, and draws everything itself. Important is, that you still can attach a sysmenu to the window, so that a right click on the taskbar button gives the usual options.

If you want to get fancy you can process the WM_NCPAINT message to perform frame and title drawing yourself on a decorated window: http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/dd145212(v=vs.85).aspx

But the easier solution actually is to just emulate the standard Windows decorations and synthesize the events the standard buttons do.

Comment: thanks~ so can I change color with standard windows decoration?

Comment: @user1560323: Well, you emulate Windows' original decoration drawing. The GDI has functions for drawing the standard control shapes. It's been an awful long time since I last dabbled with those things, but IIRC you can not change the system colors for a single window only; so you'll have to draw everything yourself.